# "command-not-found==0.2.44" in pip's freeze

Tags: python, pip

The output of `pip freeze` on my machine has included the following odd line:

```
command-not-found==0.2.44
```

When trying to install requirements on a different machine, I got the obvious `No distributions at all found for command-not-found==0.2.44`. Is this a `pip` bug? Or is there any real python package of that name, one which does not exist in `pypi`?

Comment: There is actually a package in Ubuntu called `command-not-found`.  It is the handler which suggests what package your command is contained in when you run an unresolved command.  How that ended up in your pip freeze I'm not sure.

Comment: Try creating your virtualenv with the `--no-site-packages` option to make sure no unwanted crap from the OS ends up in there.

Comment: That was freezing my site, not a virtual environment. When freezing my virtual env, this does not happen.

Comment: Does `pip install command-not-found==0.2.44` work fine on the current machine, but not on the different machine?  Then it might be a case of sources missing in apt.

Comment: Indeed, in the current machine it says `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): command-not-found==0.2.44 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but maybe make a diff on local and remote files `/etc/apt/sources.list` and see what's up

Comment: I've never seen pip index apt sources... http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user_guide.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, as mentioned in the follow up comments, Ubuntu has a python package, installed via dpkg/apt that is called "python-commandnotfound"

```
 $apt-cache search command-not-found 
 command-not-found - Suggest installation of packages in interactive bash sessions
 command-not-found-data - Set of data files for command-not-found.
 python-commandnotfound - Python 2 bindings for command-not-found.
 python3-commandnotfound - Python 3 bindings for command-not-found.
```

As this is provided via apt, and not available in the pypi repo, you won't be able to install it via pip, but pip will see that it is installed. For the purposes of showing installed packages, pip doesn't care if a package is installed via apt, easy_install, pip, manually, etc.

In short, if you actually need it on another host (which I assume you don't) you'll need to `apt-get install python-commandnotfound`.